# What does the phrase "slid down tubes" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "slid down tubes" in the following sentence from the description of the game "Minion Rush":

For six and a half harrowing minutes, we ran up ramps and slid down tubes, steered around boxes and into hapless bystanders, until we hit a surfboard that refused to budge. ([Apple's App Store](https://apps.apple.com/bg/story/minion-rush/id1385190513))

I got a reference to the word "tubes" here:

> While you run, you encounter a series of obstacles, from a range of
> metal rockets to glass transportation tubes for the minions. ([Venture Beat](https://venturebeat.com/community/2013/07/22/despicable-mes-minion-rush-is-addictive-fun-but-runs-into-nothing-new-territory/))

I am still not sure about the meaning of the phrase "slid down tubes".

Comment: Do you understand **ramps and tubes**?? Think of a Fun Park. Try google images. If you enter a tube at one end at the top, you then slide down it. If you did that yesterday,  you slip down it. slide, slid, slid

Comment: Whoops, slid down.

Answer (score 1):

“slid down tubes” is not an idiom; the normal meaning from the dictionary applies for each word:

“slid” is the (irregular) past tense of “slide”.

“down” is the direction gravity pulls you.

“tube” is a hollow cylinder.

If you get in the top of a (tilted) tube and let go, you will slide down to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

[image: ramps and tubes]

There are at least two ramps to walk  up in that picture and a curly tube to slide down. slide down=you sit down in the tube and slide, like a kid.

playsi.com for the picture
[image]

The ramp is on the far left side....and the half-tube is right in the front!